# Python: Try three times a function until all failed

Tags: python, design-patterns, error-handling

I am writing in `Python` 2.7 and encounter the following situation. I would like to try calling a function three times. If all three times raise errors, I will raise the last error I get. If any one of the calls succeed, I will quit trying and continue immediately.

Here is what I have right now:

```
output = None
error = None
for _e in range(3):
    error = None
    try:
        print 'trial %d!' % (_e + 1)
        output = trial_function()
    except Exception as e:
        error = e
    if error is None:
        break
if error is not None:
    raise error
```

Is there a better snippet that achieve the same use case?

Comment: Note that you are using return outside of a function so this code won't even run. Code that you post here should be a minimal working example,

Comment: @lanAuld well then, updated question:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use decorator

```
from functools import wraps

def retry(times):

    def wrapper_fn(f):

        @wraps(f)
        def new_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
            for i in range(times):
                try:
                    print 'try %s' % (i + 1)
                    return f(*args,**kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    error = e
            raise error

        return new_wrapper

    return wrapper_fn

@retry(3)
def foo():
    return 1/0;

print foo()
```

Comment: A decorator is a good idea where *all* calls to a function should be retried - consider including [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to retain docstrings.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one possible approach:

```
def attempt(func, times=3):
    for _ in range(times):
        try:
            return func()
        except Exception as err:
            pass
    raise err
```

A demo with a `print` statement in:

```
>>> attempt(lambda: 1/0)
Attempt 1
Attempt 2
Attempt 3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    attempt(lambda: 1/0)
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 8, in attempt
    raise err
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

---

If you're using Python 3.x and get an `UnboundLocalError`, you can adapt as follows:

```
def attempt(func, times=3):
    to_raise = None
    for _ in range(times):
        try:
            return func()
        except Exception as err:
            to_raise = err
    raise to_raise
```

This is because the `err` is cleared at the end of the `try` statement; per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> When an exception has been assigned using `as target`, it is cleared
> at the end of the except clause.

Comment: i know its an old answer. As cool as it looks, it seems to no longer work on python 3, and yields `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'err' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @murison thanks for pointing it out! Interestingly I see that behaviour even if I add `err = None` to the start of the function, something must be happening with the `as` context binding.

Comment: yup, i ended up with exacly the same . i dont like that extra overhead...

Comment: Let's say I want to pass a function with an argument to this attempt() function. How can I do this without that function executing before it is passed? To clarify: I do not want to execute the function and pass it's outcome to the attempt() function.

Comment: @AxelKöhler pass a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the debug output and the ancient Python dialect, this looks good. The only thing I would change is to put it into a function, you could then simply return the result of trial_function(). Also, the `error = None` then becomes unnecessary, including the associated checks. If the loop terminates, error must have been set, so you can just throw it. If you don't want a function, consider using `else` in combination with the for loop and breaking after the first result.

```
for i in range(3):
    try:
        result = foo()
        break
    except Exception as error:
        pass
else:
    raise error
use_somehow(result)
```

Of course, the suggestion to use a decorator for the function still holds. You can also apply this locally, the decorator syntax is only syntactic sugar after all:

```
# retry from powerfj's answer below
rfoo = retry(3)(foo)
result = rfoo()
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across a clean way of doing the retries. There is a module called retry.

- First install the module using

  ```
  pip install retry
  ```
- Then import the module in the code.

  ```
  from retry import retry
  ```
- Use `@retry` decorator above the method, We can pass the parameters to the decorator. Some of the parameters are `tries` , `delay` , `Exception`.

**Example**

```
    from retry import retry

    @retry(AssertionError, tries=3, delay=2)
    def retryfunc():
        try:
            ret = False
            assert ret, "Failed"
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            raise ex
```

- The above code asserts and fails everytime, but the retry decorator retries for **3 times** with a delay of **2 seconds** between retries. Also this only retries on **Assertion failures** since we have specified the error type as **AssertionError** on any other error the function wont retry.